# Failed to upload my android app to playbook "debug token issue date missing or in the future"

Tags: android, portability, blackberry-playbook

I have enabled Debug Mode with the correct debug token, but I'm still getting the annoying message: "Failed to upload my android app to playbook "**debug token issue date missing or in the future**"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to `set the right date and time` in my playbook, now it works like a charm!